# Debug Ipad web app on Windows

Tags: html, css, windows, ipad

I've got site that is correctly displayed on desktop version but has few bugs on iPad. What's the simplest way to detect problems if my OS is Windows?

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1 - Free, local machine debugging**

You may use Safari browser for Windows ([download Safari 5.1.7](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1531)).

*Steps*

1. Enabling Develop menu in menu bar (Press 'Alt' key to open menu bar. Then follow to Edit menu > Preferences > Advanced tab. Find this option at the bottom.)
2. Then, follow through Develop menu > User Agent. Select iPad, iPhone etc.

There are more options in the Develop menu (e.g. Show Web Inspector) to help with your JavaScript etc debugging.

Credits to [How to debug iPhone and iPad web applications, using Safari.](http://www.spiraltrack.com/blog/how-debug-iphone-and-ipad-web-applications-using-safari)

**Option 2 - Paid, browser-based access to target browser/OS/machine**

I've personally used http://www.browserstack.com/ and it lets you test the functionality on a wide combination. However debugging may not be as convenient here as it would be on a local machine.

There may be more companies providing similar services.

**Beware of basic online emulators**

As mentioned [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556522/debug-ipad-web-app-on-windows#comment15284956_11556751), be wary of 'emulator' websites. Example: A website I ran into claimed to emulate iPhone, with a picture of iPhone, and inside it was an `iframe`, being dutifully rendered by the browser *I opened that website in* (Firefox).

Answer (score -1):

The best way I can think of(depending of your implementation) is to use the firefox plugin
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/

It allows you to switch to all sort of devices and see how they would appear on another device.

Here http://www.ampercent.com/test-website-design-iphone-ipad-mobile-devices/7075/ is a quick guide on getting you started.

There are also user-agent switchers for other browsers than FF like Chrome. Do a google search and try for yourself which one you like.

Comment: Chrome 22.0.1210.0 canary allows changing user-agent. My main problem is different webkit versions between desktop Chrome and mobile version

Comment: "see how they would appear on another device" — No, it doesn't. It lets you see what content they would get served. It doesn't make Firefox render that content in the same way that a different browser would.